# JsonParser for android does not work

Tags: android, json

I have a `JSONObject` like [this](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=e1657eaf48d876ebf27a38d9fa0ea9fb)

I wrote a `JSON` parser but it's not working. I know the problem is in the parser because my list don't sent any null errors. This is my parser:

```
    class exTourParser {


     ArrayList<GroupTour> Parse(JSONArray mainArray){
        final String SITE_NAME="sitename";
        final String TOURNOMENT_SPEED = "speed";
        final String HOUR = "hour";
        final String BUY_IN = "buyin";
        final String MINUTE = "min";
        final String REPLAY = "replay";
        final String GAME_MODE = "gamemode";
        final String PRIZE = "prize";
        final String DAY = "day";
        final String REBUY = "rebuy";
        final String LATE_REG = "latereg";
        final String ADD_ON = "addon";
        final String TIME = "time";
        ArrayList<GroupTour> groupTours = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i =0 ;i>mainArray.length();i++){
            try {
                JSONArray subArray = mainArray.getJSONArray(i);
                for (int j = 0; j>subArray.length(); j++){
                    JSONObject object = subArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    ChildTour child =new ChildTour();
                    GroupTour group = new GroupTour();
                    child.setSiteName(object.getString(SITE_NAME));
                    child.setTournomentSpeed(object.getString(TOURNOMENT_SPEED));
                    child.setHour(object.getInt(HOUR));
                    child.setMin(object.getInt(MINUTE));
                    child.setBuyIn(object.getString(BUY_IN));
                    child.setReply(object.getString(REPLAY));
                    child.setGameMode(object.getString(GAME_MODE));
                    child.setPrize(object.getString(PRIZE));
                    child.setDay(object.getString(DAY));
                    child.setReBuy(object.getString(REBUY));
                    child.setLateReg(object.getInt(LATE_REG));
                    child.setAddon(object.getString(ADD_ON));
                    child.setTime(object.getString(TIME));
                    group.setChildNumbers(subArray.length());
                    group.setName(object.getString(SITE_NAME));
                    group.setTours(child);
                    groupTours.add(group);
                }    
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return groupTours;    
    }    
}
```

List is `ExpandableListView` and objects of "tours" array is the groups and the objects of those objects are childs
and this how i parse it.

```
 private void prepareData(String url, final ExpandableListView listView) {
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("tours");
                exTourParser parser = new exTourParser();
                ArrayList<GroupTour> items = parser.Parse(array);
                exTourListAdapter adapter = new exTourListAdapter(getContext(),items);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    RequestQueue quew = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    quew.add(request);
}
```

Comment: not working is a vague term. show us the exception or problem you are facing..

Comment: What error youre facing??

Comment: y you used array inside array? in responce

Comment: First of all your json starts with `jsonObject` not `jsonArray` so in order to make it work you first need to extract the JsonObject first

Comment: i do that  i just orget to post it

Comment: First Of all, convert you response to JsonObject  mainObject=new  JsonObject(response.toString) and then after mainObject.getJsonArray("tours"); and after go ahead with single for loop

Comment: i m a new android developer so please can you guys say the answer the way new guys can understand?

Comment: @OsaironBest please check my below answer.

Comment: @OsaironBest Hey, Your JSON is Wrong. Check your JSON you putted in above given Link. It says wrong Syntax Error. Error is you put JsonObject inside JsonObject without Key. Check It. First Make Your Json Correct.

Comment: @OsaironBest It will be like this Corrected JSON: http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=e4d35442350035e2a58347f50d6f4166

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel i think the json should like this http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=e4d35442350035e2a58347f50d8c9eca

Comment: @OsaironBest, yes it is. Now its easy to parsing this Json.

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel i try it but i couldent can you please help me?

Comment: @OsaironBest Tell me, where you fiind problem with given JSON, & what you actually want to do?

Comment: on the Parse class second for loop and i want it for ExpandabaleListView the "tours" objects is group headers and childs are objects objects :) sorry for bad english

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161087/discussion-between-bhoomika-patel-and-osairon-best).

Answer (score 2):

Your outer is **JSONObject** not **JSONArray**. Parse it like below.

```
  private void parse(String jsonString){
    try{
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray dataArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("tours");
        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray obj = dataArray.getJSONArray(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < obj.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject obj2 = obj.getJSONObject(i);
               // Parse here
            }
        }

    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using  Gson Library to parse this json easiest way**

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
```

Use think to parse  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
 You will get pojo class like this
**1.ToursModel.Java**

```
    public class ToursModel {

    @SerializedName("tours")
    @Expose
    private List<List<Tour>> tours = null;

    public List<List<Tour>> getTours() {
    return tours;
    }

    public void setTours(List<List<Tour>> tours) {
    this.tours = tours;
    }

    }
```

**2.Tour.Java**

```
    public class Tour {

    @SerializedName("sitename")
    @Expose
    private String sitename;
    @SerializedName("speed")
    @Expose
    private String speed;
    @SerializedName("hour")
    @Expose
    private Integer hour;
    @SerializedName("min")
    @Expose
    private Integer min;
    @SerializedName("buyin")
    @Expose
    private String buyin;
    @SerializedName("replay")
    @Expose
    private String replay;
    @SerializedName("gamemode")
    @Expose
    private String gamemode;
    @SerializedName("prize")
    @Expose
    private String prize;
    @SerializedName("day")
    @Expose
    private String day;
    @SerializedName("rebuy")
    @Expose
    private String rebuy;
    @SerializedName("latereg")
    @Expose
    private Integer latereg;
    @SerializedName("addon")
    @Expose
    private String addon;
    @SerializedName("time")
    @Expose
    private String time;
    @SerializedName("tournamet")
    @Expose
    private String tournamet;

    public String getSitename() {
    return sitename;
    }

    public void setSitename(String sitename) {
    this.sitename = sitename;
    }

    public String getSpeed() {
    return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(String speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
    }

    public Integer getHour() {
    return hour;
    }

    public void setHour(Integer hour) {
    this.hour = hour;
    }

    public Integer getMin() {
    return min;
    }

    public void setMin(Integer min) {
    this.min = min;
    }

    public String getBuyin() {
    return buyin;
    }

    public void setBuyin(String buyin) {
    this.buyin = buyin;
    }

    public String getReplay() {
    return replay;
    }

    public void setReplay(String replay) {
    this.replay = replay;
    }

    public String getGamemode() {
    return gamemode;
    }

    public void setGamemode(String gamemode) {
    this.gamemode = gamemode;
    }

    public String getPrize() {
    return prize;
    }

    public void setPrize(String prize) {
    this.prize = prize;
    }

    public String getDay() {
    return day;
    }

    public void setDay(String day) {
    this.day = day;
    }

    public String getRebuy() {
    return rebuy;
    }

    public void setRebuy(String rebuy) {
    this.rebuy = rebuy;
    }

    public Integer getLatereg() {
    return latereg;
    }

    public void setLatereg(Integer latereg) {
    this.latereg = latereg;
    }

    public String getAddon() {
    return addon;
    }

    public void setAddon(String addon) {
    this.addon = addon;
    }

    public String getTime() {
    return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
    }

    public String getTournamet() {
    return tournamet;
    }

    public void setTournamet(String tournamet) {
    this.tournamet = tournamet;
    }

    }
```

After Parsed the json you have to use the parsing like this

```
Gson mGson=new Gson;
        ToursModel toursModel=new ArrayList();
        example=mGson.fromJson("json object string",ToursModel.class);
        toursModel.get(0).getSitename();
```

Like Above you can access the response pojo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

try {
      JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("tours");
      Log.e("=>", "" + jsonArray);
      for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

       JSONArray value = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);        

        for (int j = 0; j < value.length(); j++) {

            JSONObject obj2 = value.getJSONObject(i);

            String sitename = obj2.getString("sitename");
            String speed = obj2.getString("speed");
            String hour = obj2.getString("hour");
            String min = obj2.getString("min");
            String buyin = obj2.getString("buyin");
            String replay = obj2.getString("replay");
            String gamemode = obj2.getString("gamemode");
            String prize = obj2.getString("prize");
            String day = obj2.getString("day");
            String rebuy = obj2.getString("rebuy");
            String latereg = obj2.getString("latereg");
            String addon = obj2.getString("addon");
            String time = obj2.getString("time");

        }

      }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: what is the problem in this answer.

Comment: after second for loop i wrote Log.i(some,value.toString());        but nothing happend sorry for bad english

Comment: you can try   for (int j = 0; j < value.length(); j++) {
                        String somevalue = value.getString(i);  Log.e("Some Value","=>" + somevalue) }

Comment: add this line after second for loop

Comment: JSONArray subArray = mainArray.getJSONArray(i);
                Log.i("json2",subArray.toString());  this is the problem

Comment: please add your Log after first for loop.